# prevent IE from wrap in P element in contenteditables

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contenteditable

Suppose we have a contenteditable `div` in a page, when user starts to type to this `div`, IE wraps the user input into a `p` element, but FF does not
Now my question is how to prevent IE from this behavior?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic snippet for the task, you can develope it further.

```
function keyDown (e) {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;    
    range.pasteHTML('<br>');
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}

if (pad.attachEvent) {
    pad.attachEvent('onkeydown', keyDown);
}
```

The code is using IE's legacy selection/range and eventhandling models, so it works only in IEs. You can play with the code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8R9V/).